# How to make filter by different attribute values in laravel

Tags: laravel, search, filter

I tried to make filter shop articles depend on checkboxes similar to [tehnomanija](https://www.tehnomanija.rs/bela-tehnika/kombinovani-frizideri) or [Amazon product filtering](https://www.amazon.com/s?i=electronics&bbn=1266092011&rh=n%3A172282%2Cn%3A1266092011%2Cn%3A172659&field-shipping_option-bin=3242350011&pf_rd_i=16225009011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=85a9188d-dbd5-424e-9512-339a1227d37c&pf_rd_r=T6BT67YR8YF7XH3C7PE7&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-5&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1588978526&rnid=1266092011&ref=sr_nr_n_13) product filtering my checkboxes using laravel. Each article can have a maximum of one attribute and one value related to that attribute.

I done this :

```
AttributeValue::whereIn('id', $attributeValues)->orderBy('attribute_id')
        ->select('id', 'attribute_id')->get()
        ->each(function ($item) use (&$attributes) {
            if (!isset($attributes[$item->attribute_id])) {
                $attributes[$item->attribute_id] = [];
            }
            $attributes[$item->attribute_id][] = $item->id;
        });
```

which works great, make a group of selected ids in the different subarray. But I am not sure is that OK query:

```
$articles->where(function ($q1) use ($attributes) {
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            $q1->whereIn('attr.attribute_value_id', $attribute);
        }
    });
```

But that does not give me results like in these example pages.
For example, I want if I try to find the TVs related to this:

- Model Years: 2020 and 2019
- Connectivity Type: Bluetooth and USB
- Refresh Rate: 60Hz
  And results will back me a list of products that have the model year 2019 OR 2020 with Connectivity Type Bluetooth OR USB AND Refresh Rate 60Hz

Here is how the database looks like:

```
articles:
id name
1  Whirlpool Washing machine

attributes:
id name
1  Color
2  Size
3  Type

attribute_values
id  attribute_id name
 1  1            Red
 2  1            White
 3  1            Black
 4  3            Freestanding
 5  4            Built-in

article_attribute_values
id  article_id  attribute_value_id
1   1           1
2   1           4
```

Comment: Do you want to perform the `OR` operation between product attributes like product match with any of these attributes or you need `AND` operation that products should have all of these attributes matched

Comment: OR between values in the same attribute like "Connectivity Type"( Bluetooth OR USB OR Ethernet) and AND between each attribute (Connectivity Type AND Refresh Rate AND Model Years)

Comment: Ok so can you show us your model mappings article and attributes and a sample data how these attributes are saved in database ?

Comment: Added some example and database scheme related to that

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in your question you are trying to match things that are one thing or the other, in that case you should use `orWhere` in your loop

```
$articles->where(function ($q1) use ($attributes) {
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $q1->orWhere('attr.attribute_value_ida', '=', $attribute);
    }
});
```

Comment: not really :( take a look at my comment in question on the first comment

Comment: I updated my question maybe you will get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone also has some issue. I find a solution for this problem and like to share with you:

```
foreach ($attributes as $key => $values) {
        $articles->leftJoin('article_attribute_values as attr' . $key, 'attr' . $key . '.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
            ->where(function ($q1) use ($values, $key) {
                foreach ($values as $value) {
                    $q1->orWhere('attr' . $key . '.attribute_value_id', $value);
                }
            });
    }
```

If you use only one join it didn't work, need to have a number of joins how many attributes you have in the query, and in each join do subquery with OR where you compare each selected value.